# Updating List element with Primefaces JSF and Java

Tags: string, list, jsf, primefaces

I run my project with wildfly and I want to edit List elements with primefaces, I tried 2 different options and I got those errors:

- First Option: *SEVERE [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.context] (default task-4)
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because the return value of "jakarta.el.ValueReference.getBase()" is null*
- Second Option: *SEVERE [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.context] (default task-4)
  jakarta.faces.component.UpdateModelException: jakarta.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /referenceEditor.xhtml @59,95 value="#{cc.attrs.reference.program[0]}": null*

My List is not null because it's showing the good value before editing, but it is when I click on validate that it's saying that my List is null.

Here is the code
JSF Page:

```xml
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="reference" type="test.beans.ReferenceBean" required="true"/>
    <composite:attribute name="create" type="boolean" required="true" default="false"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
<p:outputPanel rendered='#{not referenceEditorView.showResult}'>
    <p:outputPanel class="referenceFormContainer">

        <div class="referenceInputContainer">
            <h:outputText class="defaultLabel" value="#{msg['datatable-localisation-column']} : "/>
            <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.reference.localisation}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="referenceInputContainer">
            <h:outputText class="defaultLabel" value="#{msg['datatable-program-column']} : "/>
            <!-- First Option -->
            <ui:repeat var="item" itemValue="#{item}" value="#{cc.attrs.reference.program}">
                    <p:inputText value="#{item}" style="width:50px"/>
            </ui:repeat>
            <!-- Second Option (both of them not working) -->
            <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.reference.program[0]}" style="width:50px"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.reference.program[1]}" style="width:50px"/>
            <p:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.reference.program[2]}" style="width:50px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="databaseButtonsContainer">
            <p:commandButton class="navigationChoiceButton" value="Valider" update="@form"
                             action="#{referenceEditorView.validate(cc.attrs.create, cc.attrs.reference)}"/>
        </div>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Bean Class

```java
public class ReferenceBean implements Serializable {
    private List<String> program;

    public List<String> getProgram() {
        return program;
    }

    public void setProgram(List<String> program) {
        this.program = program;
    }

    public static ReferenceBean fromReference(Reference reference) {
        ReferenceBean referenceBean = new ReferenceBean();
        referenceBean.setProgram(reference.getProgram());
        return referenceBean;
    }

    public Reference toReference() {
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.setProgram(this.getProgram());
        return reference;
    }
}
```

ReferenceEditorView Class

```java
@Named("referenceEditorView")
@ViewScoped
public class ReferenceEditorView implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReferenceEditorView.class);

    private boolean success = false; //with getter

    private boolean showResult = false; //with getter

    @Inject
    private ReferenceService referenceService;


    public void validate(boolean create, ReferenceBean referenceBean) {
        Reference reference = referenceBean.toReference();
        if (create)
        {
            LOGGER.info("Creating reference : " + reference);
            success = referenceService.createReference(reference) != null;
        } else
        {
            LOGGER.info("Updating reference : " + reference);
            success = referenceService.updateReference(reference);
        }
        showResult = true;
    }
}
```

Mapping classs

```java
public class ReferenceMapper implements RowMapper<Reference> {

    @Override
    public Reference mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.setProgram(List.of(rs.getString("reference_program").split(";")));

        return reference;
    }
}
```

Reference Model Class

```java
public class Reference {
    List<String> program;

    public Reference() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public List<String> getProgram() {
        return program;
    }

    public void setProgram(List<String> program) {
        this.program = program;
    }
}
```

Both of the options are not working but without the 'program' value in the form everything is working perfectly. So, how do I edit List elements with PrimeFaces

I would like to add that my `List<String>` is initialised in my model 'Reference' and in my bean 'ReferenceBean', but it doesn't work by initialising with the @PostConstruct in my bean class by doing something like that in ReferenceBean class:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initialise() {
    program = new ArrayList<>();
    while (program.size() <= 3) {
        program.add("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a solution to my problem, I replace my List<String> by an array of String: String[]
And everything works fine, without @PostConstruct initialise.